# Asking Soft questions about biological terminology

Tags: discussion

I have a soft question about biological  *terminology*. I want to know if biologists anticipate 'simplifying and unifying' terms across all branches of biology, the way it's the case in mathematics or computer science, say.

**Is this is an appropriate question for this site?**

Note that I'm a newcomer to the site, and my biology knowledge is very limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question looks to me more like one inviting discussions, which makes it a bad fit for an SE site. It's also pretty vague, which usually doesn't help.

So I don't think that question would work well on our site.

Comment: I agree, that's more of a forum question.